# Get user name value in ConfigureExtraProperties() in abp framework

Tags: c#, abp

I have added custom controls using ConfigureExtraProperties in ModuleExtensionConfigurator.cs file.

I need Identity control values in the ConfigureExtraProperties method.
For example user.UserName value, because I should add custom control only based on the user name.

```
user.AddOrUpdateProperty(
UserConsts.DefaultMaintenancePropertyName,
options =>
{
options.Validators.Add(context =>
{
var DefaultManint = blnDefaultMaint;

                      if (blnDefaultMaint == true )
                      {
                          context.ValidationErrors.Add(
                              new ValidationResult(
                                  strDefaulMaintUser + " is the current default maintenance contact.There Can Only be One default maintenance contact per Property.",
                                  new[] { UserConsts.DefaultMaintenancePropertyName }
                              )
                          );
                      }
                  });                     
              });
```